# Angular attempt showing object HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to learn Angular2 (I know it's Alpha, but best to learn the new stuff), and am trying to make a very basic component which loads a template.

My component looks like this:

```
var AppComponent = ng.Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html'

    })
        .Class({

            constructor: function () {
                console.log('my-app loaded...');
                this.firstname = "Craig";
            },

            writeLog() {
                alert(this.firstname);
            }
        });
```

When I had my template code incline in the component, I got the expected results. I am now trying to use a separate html file for the html.

My html file looks like this:

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello there, {{firstname}}</h1>
    <button (click)="writeLog()">Click me</button>  
</div>
```

The screen loads, but it says:

> Hello there, [object HTMLInputElement]

However, which I click the button, it gets the right value from the component (Craig).

Why is the html not rendering the {{first name}} property, but the button (Alert method, within the component, so maybe a privacy issue?) is? I'm guessing I need to make the "first name" more public or something?

Comment: Are you sure is that all your code? It's really weird that prints [HTMLInputElement](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-input-element)

Comment: Yes, that is a copy and paste of the full HTML. It's loaded from my main index.html within a <my-app></my-app> thing (Sorry, don't know the right terminology yet).